# isGUIInitialized() is false, now what?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I been looking at some code and I find people doing

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     new ExampleCode();
      }
 ExampleCode () {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        if (EventQueueMonitor.isGUIInitialized()) {
          guiInitialized();
        } else {
          EventQueueMonitor.addGUIInitializedListener(this);
        }
  }
```

Which makes sense, but now my question is how they keep the code running. To my understanding the code goes to main--->ExampleCode--->Run and then it stops because GUI was not initialized. Does any of the calls start the GUI else where? I use the same steps on my program, but my GUI is not initialized.

Two of my example codes:

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/accessibility/docs/jaccess-1.1/examples/Explorer/Explorer.java

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AGUItoshowaccessibleinformationcomingfromthecomponentsinan.htm

Comment: I've never seen (or used) code examples like that. I take my code examples from the [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) which never check the EventQueueMonitor.

Comment: Do you have any idea why would anyone take the trouble to check EventQueueMonitor? Not 100% sure, but I think it needs to be check if you want to interact with another java client.

Comment: @Juan The link you posted has detailed reason in comments. It also implements GuiinitializedListener, the method of this interface will be called when Swing stops initializing itself.

Comment: @Juan no idea, that really grey area for me, I never touched that, this API required some stress test, then could be some ..., I marked your question, maybe is there somebody who know about that something, some another fellow traveller

Comment: @UsmanSaleem The problem is that I have no idea why the GUI subsystem is not initialized properly and how to correct it. The main example that I want to reproduce is this http://yarrg.chiark.net/download/jarrg/jarrg-source.tar.gz Thanks for the help so far you two

Comment: The example you posted is using accessibility related features, hence it is possible that the initialization may take more time. The practice that we follow while using Swing is to avoid heavy initialization on event queue. What the original author's logic does is that he waits for swing jframe etc. to initialize completely, then he initialized his own components.

Comment: //  Check to see if the GUI subsystem is initialized correctly. (This is needed in JDK 1.2 and higher). If it isn't ready, then we have to wait.
    if (EventQueueMonitor.isGUIInitialized()) {
      createGUI();
    } else {
      EventQueueMonitor.addGUIInitializedListener(this);
    }
  }
  public void guiInitialized() {
    createGUI();
  }

Comment: The actual initialization logic is written in createGUI method, which will either be called by Swing or by your own logic. You program will not terminate, since Swing uses its own non-daemon thread (i.e. unless you call System.exit, your swing program will not terminate).

Comment: @Usman Saleem consider to move your comments to an answer so I can vote for it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you posted is using accessibility related features, hence it is possible that the initialization may take more time. The practice that we follow while using Swing is to avoid heavy initialization on event queue. What the original author's logic does is that he waits for swing jframe etc. to initialize completely, then he initialized his own components.

> ```
> // Check to see if the GUI subsystem is initialized correctly. (This is needed in JDK 1.2 and higher). If it isn't ready, then we have to wait. 
>
>   if (EventQueueMonitor.isGUIInitialized()) { 
>     createGUI(); 
>   } else { 
>     EventQueueMonitor.addGUIInitializedListener(this); 
>   } 
> } 
>
> public void guiInitialized() { 
>   createGUI(); 
> }
> ```

The actual initialization logic is written in createGUI method, which will either be called by Swing or by your own logic. You program will not terminate, since Swing uses its own non-daemon thread (i.e. unless you call System.exit, your swing program will not terminate).

Comment: Okay, I suppose this is going to sound really stupid. What I understood is that on my createGUI() I was going to create all my GUI components, add JLabel, JPanel, etc. It seems that I need to do it in the same method that has this piece of code. What I dont understand now is what type of code should I write in my createGUI() method. In the example there is a listener, but there is also a listener before. Not sure why createGUI exist now.

Comment: Your confusion is valid. This particular example is waiting for Swing to initialize all its underlying resources before you start adding your own JLabel, JPanel etc. If you look into Sun's example, it is more clear. The constructor checks if Swing's own system is initialized, if it is, call your initialization logic, if it isn't, register a listener with Swing event queue, so that when Swing finish initializing itself, it calls listener method (defined in your class) which in turn will call createGUI.

Comment: Here is my advise, call CreateGUI with or without EventQueue technique, chances are you won't feel any difference. The usage of EventQueue technique is to give JVM/Swing a chance to initialize itself completely before you attempt to add your "assistive" components.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example based on examples from the Swing tutorial:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        add( new JLabel("Label") );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new SSCCE() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: comforting that even you haven't seen everything :-) @Usman Saleem comments are right to the spot, and nicely explained

Comment: @kleopatra, There are plenty of things I haven't seen. I'm sure you've forgotten more than I know :)